# Http Get method returning object moved

Tags: android, html, http-get

I am an novice and working on android app. My app was working fine till the host did not set his web page to redirect to some other page. Now i am getting an html page code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Object Moved</H1> this document may be found <a href="some url">here</a>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Tried conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); but still of no use. if i use GET method i get this but on using POST method am getting null with lots of spaces. Please help.

```
enter code here
```

Here is my code in doinbackground()

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... param) {
try
{
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(){
 @Override
  protected RedirectHandler createRedirectHandler() {
    return new DefaultRedirectHandler(){
  @Override
  public boolean isRedirectRequested(HttpResponse response,     HttpContext context) {

                                rep="httpclient redirect";
                                return false;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                };
                   HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(param[0]);
                    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS,  false);
                   httppost.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, Boolean.FALSE);
 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
                   String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
                   rep+=responseBody;


            }
 catch (Exception e)
            {
                if(e.getMessage()==null)
                    rep+="No response from server";
                else
                rep+="Error: " + e.getMessage();
            }
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: You should set `setInstanceFollowRedirects` to `true` i.e  `conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);` ,if you want to follow redirects.

Comment: Sorry but i do not want to follow redirect. i was actually using a response which was given by a particular page on host.

Answer (score 0):

So... What's your question? If host moved file there's not something that we can fix.. you just should redirect to moved resource and get information from there..

Comment: actually they dint moved any thing i had a talk with them and they have set a redirect on their home page rest all pages and folders of that website is still their and at work which can be used so when i try to reach www.somewebsite.com/mypage.aspx?somevar=12(which earlier was working fine) on the browser it gets navigated but i dont want it to navigate in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I used to face this situation, if I understand what you need correctly.
The situation is you request to some url and the response is HTTP 302 move temporarily or sort of that, but you need the information from that response.

try this

```
 final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);


    // Create No Redirect HttpClient
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(){

        @Override
        protected RedirectHandler createRedirectHandler() {
            return new DefaultRedirectHandler(){
                @Override
                public boolean isRedirectRequested(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "HttpClient Redirect");
                    return false;
                }
            };
        }
    };

    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);


    // Prepare Login Request



    HttpPost postLogin = new HttpPost(URL_LOGIN);

    if(username == null || password == null){
        throw new LoginFailException();
    }


    String params1 = URLEncoder.encode("member[email]","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"utf-8");
    String params2 = "&"+URLEncoder.encode("member[crypted_password]","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"utf-8");
    String params3 = "&"+URLEncoder.encode("action","utf-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("login","utf-8");
    String params4 = "&"+URLEncoder.encode("redirect","utf-8")+"=";




    postLogin.setEntity(new StringEntity(params1+params2+params3+params4));
    postLogin.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    postLogin.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    postLogin.addHeader("User-Agent", "Dalvik/1.4.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.7; Full Android on x86 Emulator Build/GINGERBREAD)");



    HttpResponse respLogin = httpClient.execute(postLogin, httpContext);
```

from this implementation you can read data from redirect response

Comment: I tried above code but now It is coming in catch and showing "Moved Permanently" exception after a long pause. should i share some code so i am editing my post please check and help

Comment: this is all my code the url return 302 Moved Permanently too. from this implementation I can get result from response 302 Moved Permanently

FYI from above, I edited

Comment: At last i finally was able to convince my my hosting company to change navigation from **server side** to client side and now my code is working fine. I guess their is **no official way to stop server side navigation from android app**.